# Python Flask - Which file is used to log?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am taking over a Flask / Python website and discovering a 200-files-code.
I don't know Flask that much. 
How can I know in which file are the logs ? 
I am wishing to search for the line like : "app.logger.filehandler(logging_file_path)". Which method should I look for ?

I have :

```
app.logger_name     = 'jaccede'

@app.before_request
def session_start():
    g.logger               = app.logger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask uses the the [standard `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).  By default, log messages are sent to `sys.stdout`.

If there is no [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) call to configure the logging module, or no [handlers are added](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler), then it is usually left to the WSGI server to pipe stderr to a log file.

Comment: there are some `logging.basicConfig()`and
`logger = logging.getLogger()`but not for my main app :-(

Comment: @user3318273: `logging.basicConfig()` is global to the whole Python process.

Comment: @user3318273: so are logger objects; `logging.getLogger()` with no arguments would get the root logging object (a singleton) and the code there could configure it by adding handlers. That'd mean that any logging that propagates up to the root (the default setting) would end up in those handlers, regardless of where the code that sends messages to the log lives.

Comment: Is then the log file precised thanks to the daemonize uswgi value ??

Comment: @user3318273: uwsgi writes stderr out to a log file if daemonized, I believe, yes.

Comment: @user3318273: it sets the name of the logger; it depends on the configuration of the formatter if that value actually ends up in the logs.